# Subsonic Renames a Table Named "Media" to "Medium"

Tags: subsonic

I have a table in my SQL2005 DB named MultiMedia - after DAL generation with SubSonic v2.2, the classes that are generated are named "MultiMedium".  The table was originally named Media and this resulted in classes named Medium as well - easy enough to change the name of my table at this point in the project, but wondering if anyone else has run into this and from the team's perspective, is this a known issue?  What other naming problems might I run into as changing table names will not remain inconsequential for long.

Thanks!

Comment: an interesting side effect, for sure! Sounds like a pluralization thing. Trivia game: what else would go from ___ia to ____ium?

Comment: Does it handle Octopi -> Octopus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get one of these about once every 6 months :) - they're hysterical :). Yes - we do change Octopus to Octopi ... our inflector is pretty rad.

Anyway - you can set `fixPluralClassNames` to `false` on your provider - it will change this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090524072848/http://subsonicproject.com/configuration/config-options/